# C# MVC Error Handling IIS Express and IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, error-handling

Does a full solution exist to truly handle errors such as 404, 500, etc... on both IIS Express and IIS 7.5?

I have lost count how many articles I have read, regards Web.config, turning customErrors On, Off, etc... or commenting/uncommenting `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` from the FilterConfig.cs

Can somebody please review what I have so far and tell me what the correct configuration is to enable me to fully trap server errors on both IIS Express and IIS 7.5, display a custom error page and not the Shared/Error.cshtml that seems to get called no matter what and Application_Error is ignored.

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lastError = Server.GetLastError();

    Server.ClearError();

    var statusCode = lastError.GetType() == typeof(HttpException) ? ((HttpException)lastError).GetHttpCode() : 500;

    var httpContextWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
    routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", statusCode);
    routeData.Values.Add("exception", lastError);

    IController errorController = new ErrorController();

    var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContextWrapper, routeData);

    errorController.Execute(requestContext);

    Response.End();
}
```

**ErrorController.cs**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    private readonly Common _cf = new Common();
    private readonly string _httpReferer = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
    private readonly string _httpUserAgent = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

    public ActionResult Index(int? statusCode, Exception exception)
    {
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        try
        {
            Response.StatusCode = ((HttpException) exception).GetHttpCode();
        }
        catch (Exception tryException)
        {
            SendEmail(tryException, statusCode.ToString());

            return Redirect("/");
        }

        SendEmail(exception, Convert.ToString(Response.StatusCode));

        ViewBag.Title = statusCode == 404 ? "Page Not Found" : "Server Error";

        ViewBag.ExceptionMessage = Convert.ToString(exception.Message);

        return View("Index");
    }

    private void SendEmail(Exception exception, string errorType)
    {
        const string to = "to@domain.com";
        const string @from = "from@domain.com";

        var subject = "SendEmailError (" + errorType + ")";

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();            
        stringBuilder.Append("<p><strong>Exception Message: </strong>" + exception.Message + "</p>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<p><strong>Source: </strong>" + exception.Source + "</p>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<p><strong>Referer: </strong>" + _httpReferer + "</p>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<p><strong>IP Address: </strong>" + _cf.GetIpAddress() + "</p>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<p><strong>Browser: </strong>" + _httpUserAgent + "</p>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<p><strong>Target: </strong>" + exception.TargetSite + "</p>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<p><strong>Stack Trace: </strong>" + exception.StackTrace + "</p>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<p><strong>Inner Exception: </strong>" + (exception.InnerException != null ? exception.InnerException.Message : "") + "</p>");

        var body = stringBuilder.ToString();

        _cf.SendEmail(subject, to, from, body, null, true, null, null);
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Error

@if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        <p><strong>Exception:</strong> @Model.Exception.Message</p>
        <div style="overflow:scroll">
            <pre>@Model.Exception.StackTrace</pre>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <p><strong>Exception:</strong> @ViewBag.ExceptionMessage</p>
    }
}
```

**Error.cs**

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Error
    {
        public int HttpStatusCode { get; set; }

        public Exception Exception { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look through a project I did recently.
I only have one line in Application_Error() which is:

```
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
```

**FilterConfig.cs**

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); // Removed because ELMAH reports "cannot find Shared/Error" view instead of the exception.
    }
}
```

**ErrorPageController.cs**

```
public ActionResult DisplayError(int id)
    {
        if (id == 404)
        {
        //... you get the idea
```

**Web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage/DisplayError/500">
  <error redirect="~/ErrorPage/DisplayError/403" statusCode="403" />
  <error redirect="~/ErrorPage/DisplayError/404" statusCode="404" />
  <error redirect="~/ErrorPage/DisplayError/500" statusCode="500" />
</customErrors>
```

and right down the bottom I have this, with a handy comment to remind myself :)

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" /> <!-- Required for IIS7 to know to serve up the custom error page -->
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I'm just updating this, but please try commenting that line first... okay, with just these simple changes, does it work for you?

Comment: Thank you, I've commented out the HandleErrorAttribute, added the following to my webconfig `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index/500"><error redirect="~/Error/Index/403" statusCode="403" /><error redirect="~/Error/Index/404" statusCode="404" /><error redirect="~/Error/Index/500" statusCode="500" /></customErrors>` but still no joy, not hitting the ErrorController at all.

Comment: Try adding the PassThrough to the webconfig

Comment: Just added that too, but unfortunately no difference, still not hitting the Error Controller, just testing on IIS Express at present.

Comment: Could you please update your question to say what exactly it is doing? Where is it going? And how are you triggering the error? I usually test by using a bad url e.g. MyController/Foo

Comment: It might be that there is an error with your ErrorController actions. Take out any clever code, including the model, and try again. Does it go to the page?

Answer (score 1):

As I delved further and further, I figured out the reason for my specific issue. I had a route which was interfering.

```
routes.MapRoute("Pages", "{mainCategory}/{subCategory}/{pageName}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Pages", subCategory = UrlParameter.Optional, pageName = UrlParameter.Optional, QueryStringValueProvider = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

As the page tested `www.mydomain.com/blahblah` didn't exist, it fell into the Pages route to check if the content existed in the database and as it didn't it returned a null model which in turn returned the `View("Error"}` hence not hitting the Error Controller.

As a result I have bound a BaseController to the HomeController which features a `override void ExecuteResult` to catch the 404 error correctly.

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Pages(string mainCategory, string subCategory, string pageName)
    {
        var model = _pageDetailsRepository.GetPageDetails(mainCategory, subCategory, false);

        if (model == null)
        {
            // return View("Error")
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseController**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected new HttpNotFoundResult HttpNotFound(string statusDescription = null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult(statusDescription);
    }

    protected HttpUnauthorizedResult HttpUnauthorized(string statusDescription = null)
    {
        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(statusDescription);
    }

    protected class HttpNotFoundResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
    {
        public HttpNotFoundResult() : this(null) { }

        public HttpNotFoundResult(string statusDescription) : base(404, statusDescription) { }
    }

    protected class HttpUnauthorizedResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
    {
        public HttpUnauthorizedResult(string statusDescription) : base(401, statusDescription) { }
    }

    protected class HttpStatusCodeResult : ViewResult
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; private set; }
        public string StatusDescription { get; private set; }

        public HttpStatusCodeResult(int statusCode) : this(statusCode, null) { }

        public HttpStatusCodeResult(int statusCode, string statusDescription)
        {
            StatusCode = statusCode;
            StatusDescription = statusDescription;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }

            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCode;

            if (StatusDescription != null)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = StatusDescription;
            }

            ViewName = "Error";

            ViewBag.Title = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription;

            base.ExecuteResult(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The Web.config has `<system.web><customErrors mode="Off" /></system.web>` and `<system.webServer><httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" /></system.webServer>` thanks to VictorySaber as this ensures that IIS 7.5 passes the 404 header.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion of `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` did help :-)